# How to have float format with comma as a decimal separator in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv with string values for money numbers such as "R$2,444.99" and I read need to make reports with sums, groupbys, etc for the loaded DataFrame.

For these columns, what I've tried to do is create a custom conversion function to load it as floats:

```
def convert_reais(value: str) -> float:
    """Transforms column value to calculable float."""
    if value == "":
        return 0.0
    return float(value.replace("R$", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "."))
```

Then I am able to load the columns correctly passing a dictionary with these columns mapped with this function:

```
converters = {column_net: convert_reais, column_gross: convert_reais}

source_df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding=file_encoding, sep=";",
                        skiprows=1, converters=converters)
```

My final problem is that I need to show sums and groupbys showing "," as the decimal separator (which by default is ".". Ex.:

```
print(source_df.groupby([column_sort])[column_net].sum())
```

I've found a way to format the results with:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format
```

But I didn't find a `float_format` that changes points to commas.

I also tried loading the CSV with:

```
thousands=".", decimal=","
```

But this makes no difference since "R$" still make it loaded as a string.

Any thoughts on my approach?

Comment: You should probably read csv with `thousands='.', decimal=','`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I've updated the question.. but this does't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem.

Just follow the steps:

1. Import built-in locale module: `import locale`
2. From your shell, select desired and installed locale with your currency format from the list: `locale -a`
3. Set on python your script locale: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, yourlocale)` # ex. 'pt_BR.utf8'
4. Change pandas configuration for visualizing floats: `pd.set_option("float_format", locale.currency)`